# Can a Medtechie use Medical Tech for First Aid checks?

Tags: skills, healing, cyberpunk-2020

Can a Medtechie use Medical Tech for First Aid checks?

Or, in fact, is there any reason to, since it doesn't explicitly say a thorough patching up takes any more time than some first aid (other than not being able to use Medical Tech on oneself).

This brought up by the fact that First Aid is *not* a career skill for Medtechies.

Answer (score 7):

The CP2020 book is as vague on that subject as in many others. When we played, we assumed that to be practically true, and achieving the same mechanical effect of stabilising the patient.

On the other hand, I also ruled that a stabilisation procedure with Medical Tech is more durable than with First Aid. It would hold the patient stable for a longer time before it "expired" and the patient was unstable again. How long was dependent on the cause and severity of the trauma. I also made a habit of telling the Medtechies that expiration date ahead of time, as they would probably know better, being medical professionals.

Comment: Amen, vagueness is a constant in CP2020, by the way, anyone excited about Cyberpunk RED besides me? =D

Comment: I expect some shiny homage to 2.0.2.0. and great storytelling but not much in the innovative mechanics in the vein of Vincent Baker games. Happy that CP is getting some attention it deserved back in the 90's, but not really excited that I'll have something new to play.

Comment: I expect some changes (for good) at least on the Netrunning

Answer (score 6):

The Medical Tech (Medtech) skill is defined on p. 46 of the *Cyberpunk 2020* book:

> This is the skill used to perform major surgery and medical repairs.
>   For more descriptions of this skill in action, see *Trauma Team*, p. 116.

On page 116 of the core book, it elaborates:

> To make a successful medical skill check, you must roll a value [...]
>   Medical skill checks are made with two skills, *First Aid* or *Medical
>   Tech*.

And on p. 117, it further explains:

> A character with *Medical Tech* skills makes a check as if using the
>   *First Aid* skill, however, with *Medical Tech*, the patient will recover
>   at the rate of 1 point per day. [...] **Using *Medical Tech* skills supersedes the use of *First Aid* skills**;

So yes, Medical Tech is used instead of First Aid, which is how I've always run my games (including several Trauma Team games) and any game of CP2020 I've played has done the same.

Comment: Pages 116 and 177 of what, the GM's book?

Comment: @vonBoomslang Looks like the p. 116 reference is from the Cyberpunk 2020 core book, at least in the 2nd edition (ISBN 0-937-279-13-7). The p. "177" reference should actually be p. 117 (the next page).

Comment: Yes, that was a typo; it should be 117, thanks to V2Blast for correcting it.

Comment: Between earlier and later editions there was a 10p insertion, so depending on the relative editions, there might be a + or - 10 in page number.